# Aspect Ratio on Nero 9 for burning DVD

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, screen-capture, burning, aspect-ratio

I am currently attempting to burn a screen capture file to DVD. I will admit that I know very little about the process, the terminology, and am at a loss of how to find this information. I am using Nero 9 and am very displeased that the manuals available to me online explain very little.

My current problem is that when I burn to DVD,  my beautiful screen capture ends up being cropped. Through endless amounts of googling I am under the impression that this is due to aspect ratio. However, as windows will not tell me the resolution size for me to determine the correct aspect ratio I do not know how to proceed. Is there a way using Nero 9 for me to be able to burn my screen capture to DVD?

Any advice or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Usualy, when you burn a picture on a CD with Nero, the picture size stays the same. Maybe if you use a third party apps, it can change the pictures properties to save some space whenburning onto a CD but most of the time, it stays as is...

Comment: I think, he means video capture that is to be watched on a TV with a DVD player. I do not know the features of Nero 9. If Nero transcodes your video, then you must be able to tell it "somewhere" wich is the right aspect ratio (16:9 or 4:3). If you encode the video with an external tool, then you must look there.

Comment: Please add what kind of source file your using and it's resolution/aspect ratio (the screen capture file). If it's a screen capture of your computer screen, it will become a little more complicated due to the lack of standard ratio's

Comment: It's a video capture of the computer screen so not a static image. Currently I have a .mov file, I also have the ability to make this a flash file. I know that if I was using a Mac that I could look at the properties and see the dimensions etc, however I'm unsure how to get that information using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The screen video capture is 16:10; 16:9 or 4:3? Do you want to create a 16:9 or a 4:3 DVD?

Read up on letterboxing, pillarboxing and windowboxing to understand your options.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterbox

You can use DVD Flick (open source) to create your DVD and let the program decide the output format based on the input format:

http://www.dvdflick.net/

Or you can use ConvertXtoDVD ($) to have more options, in Settings-Video processing-Video resize options:

These are the two programs I use, I am sure there are many other options out there. Having tested Nero for creating DVDs, I did not like it, I just use it to burn the VIDEO_TS folder created by any of the two aforementioned programs.